# How to save the last logout time of a user in the database?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, action

I have been trying to register again the logout of the users in my website, but it seems to not work anymore.

the following code is the one i am working on right now

```
function user_last_logout(){
  update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_last_logout', time() );
} 
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'user_last_logout', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_current_user_id()` in your case returns 0, since your function is called after logout.

You can do this instead

```
function user_last_logout($user_id){
  update_user_meta( $user_id, '_last_logout', time() );
} 
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'user_last_logout', 10, 1 );
```

as wp_logout passes the logged out user id.

Comment: That is totally correct! I thought because I said get_current_user_id() first, it would actually get the user ID to register the data and then the action would be executed.